# Environment variable treated as string in app.config

Tags: c#, logging, environment-variables, app-config, enterprise-library

I'm not able to use any environment variable when declaring listener fileName for Microsoft Enterprise Library - logging block

It is getting treated as a string "I find a folder with the name %temp% inside next to exe file!

I have tried multiple variables all with the same results, I have tried using ${} format and same result!

`<add fileName="%ProgramData%\errors.log" header="----------------" footer="----------------" formatter="Text Formatter" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, OceanEhr.Logging" traceOutputOptions="None" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener" name="UserLog"/>`

Microsoft documentation mentions that we can use variables in fileName, so no idea what I'm missing

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff664768(v=pandp.50)

Comment: Try `${ProgramData}` instead.

Comment: I've tried and got the same result as I stated in the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try another environment variable like `%APPDATA%` or `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%`?

Comment: Same results, could it be that the Microsoft Enterprise Library in using an old? or it has nothing to do with it ? (I'm not able to figure out which vertion is the project using!)